# Syntax puzzle with derived template class and inherited member variables

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, visual-c++, g++

While porting some Windows legacy code and trying to get it to compile with gcc/clang I ran into the following problem which I don't fully understand:

```
template<typename T> class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}

    T m_var;
};

template<typename T> class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
    #if 1
        Base<T>::m_var = 0;   // fix - compiles with gcc/clang now
    #else
        m_var = 0;            // original - compiles only with MSVC++
    #endif
    }
};
```

The error from gcc/clang is:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'm_var'

Unfortunately there are hundreds of places where the unqualified member variables are referenced in the derived class methods, and I don't really want to have to change all these so that they are qualified with `Base<T>::` if I can help it.

Can anyone explain why gcc/clang seems to need this while MSVC++ doesn't, and suggest possible workarounds ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Base<T>` is a dependent base, its members are not accessible through unqualified lookup. As you noted, you can access them through `Base<T>::m_var`. Another option would be `this->m_var`.

I'm not sure there's a succinct workaround for this. One option would be to add a `T& m_var;` data member to `Derived` and initialize it to reference `Base<T>::m_var`. If you can't live with the extra reference member, you could add a `T& m_var = this->m_var;` to the start of any function with an unqualified `m_var` access.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation - presumably then MSVC++ is just wrong to compile this without complaint?

Comment: @PaulR most likely, yes. I vaguely remember that a few years ago, g++ didn't complain about this kind of code, and that I had to fix some similar code when it started enforcing the rule.

Comment: @PaulR Yeah, it's because of their lack of two-phase lookup. The member is just looked for at instantiation time and ignored when the template definition is checked AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

As @TartanLlama said, the member is not available through unqualified lookup because of the base type that depends on the template parameters. Apart from accessing it as `Base<T>::m_var` or `this->m_var`, there is a workaround that I strongly prefer since it has to be typed only once for each class member that you want to make accessible:

Simply add a `using Base<T>::m_var;` to the class definition of `Derived`. This way, `m_var`will be found by the normal name lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround suggestions - the `using ...` idea is perfect in this instance as it means that I can avoid butchering all the derived methods.

Comment: @PaulR You're welcome! Sorry that I might use the respective terms in a slightly loose/non-standard fashion. I'm not that familiar with the standardese language here...